# Setcustomvalidity not working for radio buttons

Tags: html

How to set the custom validation message for radio buttons.
Tried adding oninvalid = this.setcustomvalidity('hsjsjs').
Able to set the message but on click of radio button also getting validation message

Can anyone tell me how to reset the setcustomvalidity

Have given oninvalid event  and required attribute for both radio buttons

Answer (score -1):

please try:

`oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"`